# How to get Keyboard Layout in Mac With C++

Tags: c++, c, macos

i find below code that get keyboard layout but cant convert it to string :

---

```
TISInputSourceRef sourceRef = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSource();
```

---

If you use `CFShow(sourceRef);` you can see keyboard layout but cant convert sourceRef.

How to get keyboardLayout in string ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this objc code:

```
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

TISInputSourceRef source = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource();
NSString *s = (__bridge NSString *)(TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyInputSourceID));
```

You can probably also cast it to `CFStringRef` instead of an objc string.